# MySQL NDB Cluster architecture?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

I am looking for information that I am not able to find about MySQL cluster.

I have to justify if it is possible to install in a production environment the three types of nodes (MySQL node + Data node + MGMT Node) on the same instance EC2 (AWS)

One of the scenarios is to have two EC2 instances. The three types of nodes are installed on each instance. The MySQL cluster is active / active between the two instances. I believe this configuration is acceptable for Oracle in a development environment. But in a production environment it would not be and I would like to know why because I don't see a single point of failure.

Oracle in its documentation seems recommend 6 servers to have a fully redundant solution. Okay but why technically this requires 6 servers?

The web application that will use MySQL doesn't require a large processing capacity.

Thank you in advance for your precious help.

Nb. I'm not a DBA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put different node types on the same machine.  But...  You need to change the configuration of each.  *Running out of RAM would be really bad for performance.*

For a Web application, I see no need for the *complexity* of NDB Cluster.  Virtually all Web usages of MySQL simply use InnoDB.

Before digging into more details, please state your goals.  Redundancy?  Resiliency?  Scale?  Key-value store?  Other?  I don't hear any of those in your Question.

Comment: Hi Rick,

Thanks for your feedback.
My main purpose is the Redundancy.

Comment: MariaDB with Galera gives you a similar amount of redundancy, but less complexity.  I cannot attest to either's fitness for use on EC2.

Comment: @RickJames I read somewhere that Galera return errors on topology changes, even when a good node cames back from a network problem. Do you know if is this true?